# Android Allocating Faster than Garbage Collecting

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, profiler

I have a large app (2 year old codebase) and it's beginning to get ANRs from a number of its users.

I looked at the Profiler on Android Studio and it looks like I have been allowing deallocations for everything -- no circular references (not that this should matter) and every object type eventually gets some deallocations (keyword *EVENTUALLY*).

However, it's just that these objects aren't being deallocated as fast as they are being allocated over time. This leads to huge total count buildups e.g. 300mb total after 30 minutes of use from the usual 120mb from only 5 minutes of use.

I don't know what to do other than overhaul my code with cleaner implementations such that I don't make heavy use of the garbage collector. Is there something else I can try? Perhaps manually invoking the garbage collector or asking Android to try a different configuration for memory management? Any advice big or small would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you can invoke Garbage collector manually by

```
System.gc()
```

Also you can dump the memory usage in `Profiler` of `Android Studio`, where you get the allocation log. By this way you can identify which objects are eating the memory and can take necessary measures.